# AttributeError: 'BloomForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, bloom

I'm trying to do some basic text inference using the bloom model

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoModel

# checkpoint = "bigscience/bloomz-7b1-mt"
checkpoint = "bigscience/bloom-1b7"

tokenizer = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint, torch_dtype="auto", device_map="auto")

# Set the prompt and maximum length
prompt = "This is the prompt text"
max_length = 100000

# Tokenize the prompt
inputs = tokenizer.encode("Translate to English: Je t’aime.", return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

# Generate the text
outputs = model.generate(inputs)

result = tokenizer.result(outputs[0])

# Print the generated text
print(result)
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_444/bloom.py", line 15, in <module>
    inputs = tokenizer.encode("Translate to English: Je t’aime.", return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1265, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'BloomForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

It's running on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the `AutoModelForCausalLM` tokenizer instead of the `AutoTokenizer`.

The `AutoModelForCausalLMTokenizer` does not have an `encode()` method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were using a model class to create your tokenizer.

AutoModelForCausalLM loads a model for causal language modelling (LM) but not a tokenizer, as stated in the documentation. (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM) You got that error because the model does not have a method called "encode".

You can use `AutoTokenizer` to achieve what you want. Also, in huggingface every tokenizer's **call** is mapped to the encoding method, so you do not have to specify the method call. See below

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
checkpoint = "bigscience/bloom-1b7"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint, torch_dtype="auto", device_map="auto")

# Set the prompt and maximum length
prompt = "This is the prompt text"
max_length = 100000

# Tokenize the prompt
inputs = tokenizer("Translate to English: Je t’aime.", return_tensors="pt").to("cuda") # Same as tokenizer.encode(...)
```